# Deciding what data model to use for simple time tracking app

Tags: json, swift, core-data, swiftui

I’m creating an app that is very simple in terms of the data it needs to store but as I am brand new to app development I’m looking for advice on what is the best method to store/retrieve/change the data. 
It’s a very simple time tracking app and will need to manipulate the following data.

- A record for each new day. For each day record it will need to store

  - Start work time /date
  - Start lunch time /date
  - End lunch time /date End
    work time /date
  - Working day /bool

As the app will be used in conjunction with an existing time tracking process there is no need to store the ‘day’ record for longer than 3 months.
I’ve looked through some ways of storing data.

- UserDefaults
- CoreData
- A local JSON file

I’m leaning towards a local JSON but wondered if it’s worth looking at the other options even if it’s just to learn how they work? To keep things simple, I want to try to do as much as I can with just Swift and Swift UI as that’s all I’m familiar with.
Also I’d like the app to automatically create a new day record (at the point a new day occurs) without the user having to do anything. I’m not sure if that makes a difference with the data approach.
Any advice most welcome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If storing data inside phone local is enough for you, I recommend you to learn and use CoreData to keep it persistent. I do not think local JSON file enough for your application it is hard to keep your application persistent. I do not know UserData but I think you are talking about UserDefaults and it is useful for keeping small amount of data like userSettings or app status. For the future needs, I strongly recommend you to learn some server-side like frameworks like Vapor (you can write your server-side code using Swift language that you can adapt easily) or any other server-side frameworks.

Comment: Thanks Atalay, seems like good advice. For this app I'm trying to keep things as simple as possible so will keep the data local for now. I did mean UserDefaults and have updated the post. Cheers.

Comment: As I said, keeping too many things inside UserDefaults may not be a good idea. Also can you please mark as accepted answer if you found useful? @welshys